# SSRS 2014 issue with dataset after deployment

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

My report is running without a sweat on my dev environment. I was a happy man.

When deployed on another server, I have the following issue (see below) (less happy now )

[image: The issue]

The error is:

> The variable name '@choix_de_l_adresse' has already been declared.
>   Variable names must be unique within a query batch or stored
>   procedure.

I've checked the parameters for the dataset `adresse1`. Nothing substantial came out (see image below).

[image]

I thought it may be related to a case issue with my sql (see below) but nothing striking jumps off

```
DECLARE @choix_de_l_adresse VARCHAR(38) 

SELECT  JohnJack.Siren, 
        CASE WHEN JohnJack.Adresse1_Eco IS NULL 
            THEN '' WHEN JohnJack.Adresse1_Post IS NULL 
            THEN '' WHEN (JohnJack.Adresse1_Eco IS NOT NULL OR JohnJack.Adresse1_Post IS NOT NULL) 
                AND @choix_de_l_adresse = 'Adresse Postale' 
            THEN Adresse1_Post 
        ELSE Adresse1_Eco END AS adresse1
FROM JohnJack
```

The only workaround I've been able to find out is to delete the dataset and to recreate it from scratch.

---

Update: When I'm using `ssrs` query builder to run the query batch, it is running fine

- Do you think using a stored procedure would help? I read somewhere that text was not a good fit and when possible, a stored procedure would be better.
- Have you seen the following issue and were you be able to fix it without deleting and recreating your dataset? If the answer is yes, how did you do it?

Comment: Can you translate the error for us?

Comment: Please post the part of your stored procedure where you declare the stored proc's parameters.

Comment: Hi @Paddy, doing it right now. Give me a sec

Comment: Hi @tab-allerman, the sql you see in my question is the "stored procedure". It is not a real stored procedure `per se`.

Comment: Ok, then calling it a stored procedure is making it harder to understand your question and help you.  In that case, I recommend checking here:   https://www.google.com/search?sourceid=navclient&aq=&oq=how+to+parameterize+sql+query+in+SSRS+dataset&ie=UTF-8&rlz=1T4GGNI_enUS551US551&q=how+to+parameterize+sql+query+in+SSRS+dataset&gs_l=hp....0.0.2.82672218...........0.WiLNSp7s9UA

Comment: @TabAlleman I've use the checklist in the first result that g2o gave me. It was not helpful...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve my issue.

I created a `stored procedure`, put my sql code inside and ... voilà ! all the rows I was looking for, were retrieved